# How to make my action.payload target and display a particular item based on the button that I click on the page using Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Okay, so I am currently writing a React application using Redux and Typescript and am having trouble coming up with a solution to a problem since I am pretty new to redux. It is a restaurant online order page where I have 2 components (MenuItems.tsx and Cart.tsx) inside of an Order.tsx page as well as a Rootreducer.tsx which has all of my menu information, my root reducer and the store:

[image: Order.tsx UI]

The side to the left of the vertical black line on the page is everything within the  MenuItems.tsx component, and the right side is the Cart.tsx component. When I click Add To Cart, the food is pushed into the items[] array within my state and is displayed in the cart.

The problem is that when I click "Add to Cart" on any of the items in a section, it returns every food item within the section, or the entire array that the action.payload contains (currently it sends all 5 food item names and its prices in the payload into the cart component). While it is working code, I specifically want it so that when I click the button on a particular food item, I only want the cart to display that one item, not all 5 meals in the Starters section.

My initial Menu data that is being accessed:

```html
const initialMenu = [
  {
    section: "Starters",
    list: [
      {
        img: chickenwings,
        name: "Chicken Pub Wings",
        desc: "Served with blue cheese dip and celery sticks. Choose your style plain and crispy, mild sticky barbecue or hot spicy Louisiana sauce",
        price: "$9 for 6 wing basket, $14 for 12 wing basket",
      },
      {
        img: soupoftheday,
        name: "Soup of the Day",
        desc: "Served with Dublin Soda Bread",
        price: "$6",
      },
      {
        img: potatoskins,
        name: "Galway Potato Skins",
        desc: "Served with Irish bacon, cheddar and chives",
        price: "$9",
      },
      {
        img: friedpickles,
        name: "Fried Pickles",
        desc: "Thick-cut chips, beer battered, with house-made ranch",
        price: "$8",
      },
      {
        img: mozzarellasticks,
        name: "Mozzarella Sticks",
        desc: "Slightly breaded, golden fried and served with warm marinara sauce",
        price: "$8",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    section: "Soups & Salads",
    list: [
      {
        img: caesarsalad,
        name: "Caesar Salad",
        desc: "Crisp romaine, parmesan cheese, brioche croutons, classic dressing",
        price: "$14",
      },
      {
        img: cobbsalad,
        name: "Cobb Salad",
        desc: "Romaine, tomato, egg, red onion, avocado, blue cheese, smoked bacon",
        price: "$15",
      },
      {
        img: housesalad,
        name: "House Salad",
        desc: "Mixed greens, tomato, cucumber, croutons, shredded cheese. Can add grilled or fried chicken for $3",
        price: "$10",
      },
      {
        img: greeksalad,
        name: "Greek Chicken Salad",
        desc: "Romaine, black olives, banana peppers, tomato, cucumber, feta, and greek feta dressing",
        price: "$11",
      },
      {
        img: potatosoup,
        name: "Loaded Potato Soup",
        desc: "Topped with cheese and crispy bacon and served with dipping bread",
        price: "$7",
      },
      {
        img: beefstew,
        name: "Guinness Beef Stew",
        desc: "Braised beef, root vegetables and potatoes simmered in a Guinness broth",
        price: "$14",
      },
    ],
  },
  ...
```

Code for MenuItems.tsx:

```js
import { useAppSelector, useAppDispatch } from "../app/hooks";
import "../styles/Order.scss";
import "../App.tsx";

const MenuItems = (props: any): JSX.Element => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  // console.log(props);
  const menu = useAppSelector((state) => state.menu);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="menu-nav">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#Starters">Starters</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#Soups & Salads">Soups & Salads</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#Traditional Classics">Traditional Classics</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#Burgers & Sandwiches">Burgers & Sandwiches</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#Sides">Sides</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#Drinks">Drinks</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#Desserts">Desserts</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="item-flex">
        {menu.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index} className="">
              <h1 id={item.section}>{item.section}</h1>
              <div className="item-grid">
                {item.list.map((c, i) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={i} className="item-section">
                      <img src={c.img} alt="food image" />
                      <p>{c.name}</p>
                      <p>{c.desc}</p>
                      <p>{c.price}</p>
                      <button
                        key={c.name}
                        onClick={() =>
                          dispatch({
                            type: "ADD_TO_CART",
                            payload: item,
                          })
                        }
                      >
                        Add To Cart
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MenuItems;
```

Code for Cart.tsx:

```html
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "../app/hooks";
import "../styles/Order.scss";

const Cart = (): JSX.Element => {
  const cart = useAppSelector((state) => state.items);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  return (
    <div className="">
      <h1>Cart</h1>
      {cart.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            {item.list.map((c, i) => {
              return (
                <div key={i}>
                  <p>{c.name}</p>
                  <p>{c.price}</p>
                  <button
                    key={c.name}
                    onClick={() =>
                      dispatch({ type: "REMOVE_FROM_CART", payload: item })
                    }
                  >
                    Remove From Cart
                  </button>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <NavLink to="/ordercomplete">Order Complete</NavLink>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

rootReducer.tsx:

```html
type Action = {
  type: string;
  payload?: any;
};

interface CommonFood {
  img: any;
  name: string;
  desc: string;
  price: string;
}

interface FoodDetail {
  section: string;
  list: Array<CommonFood>;
}

const initialMenu = [
  ...
 };

type State = {
  menu: FoodDetail[];
  items: FoodDetail[];
};

const initialState: State = {
  menu: initialMenu,
  items: [],
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TO_CART":
      const newItems = state.items;
      console.log(newItems);
      return { ...state, items: [...newItems, action?.payload] };
    case "REMOVE_FROM_CART":
      return {
        ...state,
        items: [...state.items].filter((item) => item !== action.payload),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default rootReducer;
```

So, based on the code that I have given, how can I change the "ADD_TO_CART" action type in my root reducer so that instead of it giving all 5 items within the array, I can target one item in it? Or do I need to change something else? I know that I would need to target its index somehow to grab that particular value, but I have been struggling with what to try. Any help is immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your dispatch references the items in your menu state. Each item is in fact an object describing a menu section, not an actual cart item.

> I know that I would need to target its index somehow to grab that
> particular value, but I have been struggling with what to try.

As you've described the problem, you don’t need the index, since you're just pushing the item to the cart. You just need to pass the current food item `c` like so:

```
dispatch({ type: "ADD_TO_CART", payload: c })
```

However, if you add the same item to the cart more than once, you probably want to increment the count of that item rather than push the duplicate item to the cart.

And for this, you will need an `id` of some kind in order to know what item to increment as well as a `quantity` to track the count of each item.

### Solution

First, your `state.items` should presumably be of type `CommonFood[]` not `FoodDetail[]`, so that your cart represents individual items.

Then, `CommonFood`, or whatever you decide is used as your cart item, needs to have both an `id` and a `quantity` prop:

```
{
  name: "Fried Pickles",
  id: 0,
  quantity: 0,
  img: friedpickles,
  desc: "Thick-cut chips, beer battered, with house-made ranch",
  price: "$8",
}
```

You'll also want to have access to the current cart state in MenuItems.tsx so you can pass it to your action.

So, in MenuItems.tsx you'd have:

```
dispatch({ type: "ADD_TO_CART", payload: {cartItems, itemToAdd} })
```

Here, I've just used `cartItems` to replace `state.items` and `itemToAdd` to replace `c` from your current code. This just makes the next bits more readable.

Then, in your action:

```
case "ADD_TO_CART":
  const { cartItems, itemToAdd } = action.payload;
  
  const newCartItems = (cartItems, itemToAdd) => {
    const existingCartItem = cartItems.find(
      (cartItem) => cartItem.id === itemToAdd.id
    );

    if (existingCartItem) {
      return cartItems.map((cartItem) =>
        cartItem.id === itemToAdd.id
          ? { ...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity + 1 }
          : cartItem
      );
    }

    return [...cartItems, { ...itemToAdd, quantity: 1 }];
  };

  return { ...state, items: newCartItems };
```

In the action, we are checking if the item in the cart exists.

If it does, we increment the quantity for that item.

If not, we add the item, and we set the quantity to 1.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! After trying to change state.menu to state.items, it unfortunately clears out the entire menu and makes it blank since state.menu is currently mapping over the initialMenu data using that particular selector and displaying everything onto the page like in the photo. I also changed action.payload: item to action.payload: c already and it causes the entire screen to turn white after clicking an Add to Cart button.

Comment: Okay, so I take it menu is intended to follow the same schema as cart items. Can you provide me an example of what a valid cart item looks like? Your logic for updating the cart for each action in rootReducer seems okay to me. Might need to see useAppSelector and useAppDispatch. Did you get an error when the screen turned white?

Comment: So when you click Add to Cart, it's basically putting the name and price tags over to the cart. While the left side displays an image, name, description and price in img and p tags, it just grabs the name and price p tags and puts them to the right. For example, if I clicked the button for Soup of the Day, then the name (Soup of the Day) and price ($6) would just show up under the big cart text. And as for the error, it said "type error: cannot read property of undefined (reading 0)"

Comment: Okay, what you're describing in your latest comment sounds like an improvement over the white screen. What changed? Sounds like you are getting the desired result based on what you described in the question. In other words, the new cart item is showing in your `items` state used by the cart. Is that correct? I also updated my answer to include some other considerations. If you're starting to see the items show in the cart, then perhaps the my updated answer will be easy to try out as well.

Comment: Hopefully my updated answer makes sense. Did you make any other changes besides passing `c` to your action instead of `item`? I think you'll find that updating the shape of your cart item is going to be necessary once you start to look at tracking the count of items and getting the cart total among other things. Would be curious what other changes you made and if this is now working for you as expected. Let me know if I can be of any further help.